# Receiving divide by Zero error in ruta

Tags: java, xslt, docx4j, uima, ruta

```
org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.HtmlConverter mapAnnotations(454)
WARNING: illegal annotation offset mapping
org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.HtmlConverter mapAnnotations(454)
WARNING: illegal annotation offset mapping
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl callAnalysisComponentProcess(417)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:563)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.processFile(RutaLauncher.java:169)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.number.AbstractNumberExpression.calculate(AbstractNumberExpression.java:89)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.number.ComposedNumberExpression.getIntegerValue(ComposedNumberExpression.java:78)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.number.ComposedNumberExpression.getIntegerValue(ComposedNumberExpression.java:72)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.assignVariable(RutaStream.java:1145)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.action.AssignAction.execute(AssignAction.java:41)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.AbstractRuleElement.apply(AbstractRuleElement.java:132)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RuleElementCaretaker.applyRuleElements(RuleElementCaretaker.java:110)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.applyRuleElements(ComposedRuleElement.java:603)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.AbstractRuleElement.doneMatching(AbstractRuleElement.java:86)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallback(ComposedRuleElement.java:521)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:416)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.startMatch(RutaRuleElement.java:103)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.startMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:74)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:53)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:46)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:32)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaScriptBlock.apply(RutaScriptBlock.java:63)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaScriptBlock.apply(RutaScriptBlock.java:63)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaModule.apply(RutaModule.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:561)
```

I'm using Xslt to convert word into html. So when I use the converted html in ruta,I'm facing the above error. Is there any best solution for converting the docx into html?

Initially I used docx4j library for html conversion. But I can't convert the  docx file which contains track changes and I also received "NOT IMPLEMENTED" comments in the converted html file.

Comment: Can you extend the stacktrace especially which part of ruta throws the exception?

Comment: Can you add the rule with the ASSIGN action. You probably need to check that the divisor in the numerical expression is not 0.

Comment: Yeah I found that  that the divisor in the numerical expression is 0